# Separating HTML page into 'objects'

Tags: html

So i have an HTML file my problem is i want to create an "About Me" section in one DIV section, the issue is the About Me section is rather long and contains a lot of text and as a result of that makes the code look untidy. I mean from a functionality point of view it works but i like making HTML files look as good as i can.

Is there someway i can link my about me section from a separate HTML file containing just that info, almost has is if it was a separate class in OOP and i am in essence just calling to an 'About Me' object?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use an `<iframe>` for that, pointing to your other HTML file.

```
<html>
  <head>
  ..
  </head>
  <body>
    ...
    <iframe src="link/to/your/file.html" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" ></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Oh brilliant, thankyou very much for the suggestion, seems to be exactly what i need.